# What is the 'key' to these tantrika works?

Tags: mahayana, terminology, texts, tibetan-buddhism

At the end of this article, [First Principles of Buddha Dharma](http://www.dharmafellowship.org/library/essays/first-principles-of-buddha-dharma.htm), in the  'Summing Up' section, it says,

> In the sense of Dharma being the 'teachings' of the Buddha, the teachings that explain the Path of Awakening, we find them composed in twelve types of scripture.

and,

> (12) *Upadesa*, concerning esoteric doctrines, the equivalent to Tantra ('tradition'), in which the Buddha appears in various archetypal forms, for the illumination of beings. These tantrika works are quite numerous, but not readily comprehensible except for **those who have the correct key** to their meaning.

What is that Key ?
What is the meaning of it?
Is it a secret of that tradition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Lotus Sutra:

> He has thus taught this sutra in many places for the sake of the
>   sentient beings. Sometimes he has appeared in the form of Brahma. Sometimes
>   he has appeared in the form of Śakra. Sometimes he has appeared in the form of Īśvara. Sometimes he has appeared in the form of Maheśvara.
>   Sometimes he has appeared in the form of the great commander of the devas.
>   Sometimes he has appeared in the form of Vaiśravaṇa. Sometimes he has
>   appeared in the form of a noble emperor. Sometimes he has appeared in the
>   form of a minor king. Sometimes he has appeared in the form of a wealthy
>   man. Sometimes he has appeared in the form of a householder. Sometimes
>   he has appeared in the form of a state official. Sometimes he has appeared in
>   the form of a brahman. Sometimes he has appeared in the form of a monk, nun,
>   layman, or laywoman. Sometimes he has appeared in the form of the wife of
>   a wealthy man or a householder. Sometimes he has appeared in the form of
>   the wife of a state official. Sometimes he has appeared in the form of the wife
>   of a brahman. Sometimes he has appeared in the form of a boy or a girl. Sometimes
>   he has appeared in the form of a human, or a nonhuman such as a deva,
>   nāga, yakṣa, gandharva, asura, garuḍa, kiṃnara, or mahoraga.
>   “In this way he has expounded this sutra and saved those in the states
>   of being of hell-dwellers, hungry ghosts, animals, and those in difficult circumstances.
>   Sometimes he has transformed himself into a female in royal harems.

...

> If he is able to save them in the form of a śrāvaka, he teaches
>   the Dharma by changing himself into the form of a śrāvaka. If he is able to
>   save them in the form of a pratyekabuddha, he teaches the Dharma by changing
>   himself into the form of a pratyekabuddha. If he is able to save them in
>   the form of a bodhisattva, he teaches the Dharma by changing himself into
>   the form of a bodhisattva. If he is able to save them in the form of a buddha,
>   he teaches the Dharma by changing himself into the form of a buddha. **Thus
>   he transforms himself in various ways according to the capacities of those
>   who are to be saved.** If he is able to save them by means of parinirvāṇa, he
>   manifests parinirvāṇa to them.

Comment: Thanks, I thought about "Mudra" or 'Yogini' like things.